# Black, green, blue and light blue are pretty colorblind-unfriendly choice for code colors

Tags: discussion, design, syntax-highlighting, accessibility

Many of my colorblind friends have had trouble seeing the syntax highlighting on this website due to the choice of colors.

Can anything be done about this?

Comment: *"Can anything be done about this?"* Propose something and explain why the new is better than the old.

Comment: @Rizier123 I believe I phrased that poorly, I meant it in the sense of "are there any current feature to help solve this?" However, you're right, I'll propose something.

Comment: What do you mean have trouble reading? As in they can't see the text on the background? Because that's a more serious problem. Them not being able to see the difference in text colors - not so much.

Answer (score 6):

Since there are *many* types of vision impairments that make a one-size-fits-all solution unlikely to work for everyone, and since I'm a programmer, I present the 100% customizable solution.

1. Download a User Styles browser extension for your browser. (I've used Stylish since it has a nice editor and is available for Firefox, but there are lots of options. Options are also available for Chrome.)
2. Add a user style for StackOverflow. (And any other network sites you care to modify)
3. In the style put:

```css
// Uncomment these two lines if using Stylish on Firefox
// @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
// @-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {

  .prettyprint /* Code block */
  {
    background-color: cornsilk;
  }
  code
  {
    background-color: cornsilk;
  }

  .kwd  /* Keyword */
  {
    color: red;
  }
  .typ /* Type */
  {
    color: purple;
  }
  .lit /* Literal */
  {
    color: darkgreen;
  }
// } and add this close brace back in if using Stylish on Firefox
```

The above produces the following hideous result:

[image: Screenshot of restyle]

Look at the [Google Prettify Style Gallery](https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/styles/index.html) for a couple more complete styling options.

Comment: You deliberately made that screenshot cut off the last characters so I would try editing to fix that, right?

Comment: @rene - That's just a happy accident. :D